# Increasing application's performance

Tags: symfony

I'm creating symfony 2 application that has to be well optimized, but right now the loading times reach up to 1000ms, which is way too much. Opening the profiler gives me the following results:

- `firewall` always seems to load for 300-400ms, why does it take so long? The same situation was when I was using FOSUserBundle, now I'm using my own, very simple module, and the loading time hasn't changed.
  My routing is composed of one argument, in form of `/key1/value1/key2/value2/`
- `controller` loads about 300-400ms, same issue, why so long? Here I assume that's because of knp user bundle which I'm removing right now

The rest of the profiler seems pretty ok.

Any ideas of solving this problem?

Comment: What system/stack are you using, and you are in developer mode since you're using the Profiler?  If you are using windows, that can slow things down and is not comparable to using a linux web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful on what env your making these checks. The firewall in dev env is really slow relative to prod env.

For the controller, there is no reason to be slow... Maybe KNP bundle (as you said).

If you want to improve your performances and loading times, you should document about HHVM. It is (almost) fully compatible with Symfony2 and really improves performances.

http://hhvm.com/